# Error when persisting OneToOne relation in embed form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I have these entities in my symfony EntityBundle:
Fist `Organization.php`:

```
    class Organization
    {
    /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="organization_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @Assert\Type(
         *     type="string",
         *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
         * )
         * @Assert\NotNull()
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @ORM\Column(name="organization_name", length=255)
         */
        protected $name;
    /**
         * @var Address
         *
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="organization", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="address_id")
         */
        protected $address;
    /**
         * Set address
         *
         * @param \MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Address $address
         *
         * @return Organization
         */
        public function setAddress(\MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Address $address = null)
        {
            $this->address = $address;
            $address->setOrganization($this);

        }


        /**
         * Get address
         *
         * @return \MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Address
         */
        public function getAddress()
        {
            return $this->address;
        }
    }
```

Second, `Address.php`:

```
class Address
{
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      max = 5,
     *      maxMessage = "Votre numéro de rue doit avoir maximum {{ limit }} chiffres"
     * )
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="street_number", type="integer")
     */
    protected $streetNumber;
/**
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="string",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="street_name", length=255)
     */
    protected $streetName;
/**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Organization", mappedBy="address")
     */
    protected $organization;
/**
     * Set organization
     *
     * @param \MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization $organization
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setOrganization(\MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization $organization = null)
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get organization
     *
     * @return \MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization
     */
    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }

    /**
     * Add organization
     *
     * @param \MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization $organization
     * @return Address
     */
    public function addOrganization(\MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization $organization)
    {
        $this->organization[] = $organization;

        $organization->setOrganization($this);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is y controller in order to persist datas in the embed form:

```
public function RegistrationAction()
    {

      $organization = new Organization();

      $form = $this->createForm(new OrganizationType(), $organization)
                   ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

      $request = $this->getRequest();

      if( $request->isMethod('POST') ) {

        $form->bind($request);

        if( $form->isValid() ) {

          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $em->persist($organization);
          $em->flush();

           return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');

        }
      }

      return $this->render('MyBundle:MyFolder:Registration.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
      ));
    }
```

Here is my form type `OrganizationType.php` :

```
$builder
->add('name')
/* ... the other fields ... */
->add('address', 'collection', array(
                                     'type' => new AddressType(),
                                     'allow_add' => true,
                                     'allow_delete' => false,
                                     'by_reference' => false,
                                     'mapped' => true,
                                     ));
}
```

And finally my twig view to render the form:

```
<div>
  {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('path_action'), 'method': 'POST'}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {# .. the other fields ...#}
    {{ form_row(form.address.vars.prototype) }}
  {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Everything is working well except when I submit the form.
This error occured:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization::setAddress() must be an
>   instance of MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Address, array given,
>   called in
>   C:\wamp\www\myApp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 502 and defined,
>   'C:\wamp\www\myApp\src\MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization.php',
>   '336', array('this' => object(Organization)))  in
>   src\MyNamespace\EntityBundle\Entity\Organization.php at line 336

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
->add('address', 'collection', array(
                                 'type' => new AddressType(),
                                 'allow_add' => true,
                                 'allow_delete' => false,
                                 'by_reference' => false,
                                 'mapped' => true,
                                 ));
```

even it's a oneToOne relation you have set the form attribute type as a collection so when symfony parse the form data it wrap the address in an array, you can fix this by :

```
->add('address', new AddressType());
```

Comment: So my error is to treat this OneToOne relation like a collection field, that's right ?
Another question, your answer works well, now the problem is the label of the embedded form address, it is displayed too, can I remove him with the data-prototype like you suggest me in my other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495088/how-to-delete-embedded-form-collection-field-label-in-symfony) ?
Thank you a lot by the way.

Comment: Yes the problem was in the collection field type for you other questions you have used the default view predefined by symfony you need to use only the embedded form prototype

Comment: You rock and save my day ! Thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: You welcome mate, can you mark your other question as solved